How to write to Modbus TCP Master (Holding Register) from a TCP Slave using NModbus
I have this simple code in c# trying to write Modbus Register using nmodbus. I am not sure what I am missing, but all the Holding Registers in the Master (seen in MODScan) is 0. Not sure why?
I expected to see values in the 40001 - 40005.
public class ModbusManager
  {
      
      private static System.Timers.Timer Modbus_Poll_Timer;
      private const string PrimarySerialPortName = "COM4";
      private const string SecondarySerialPortName = "COM2";
      // public ModbusSlave _slave;
      public int _ModbusMode = 1; //0 = Serial , 1 = TCP
      private readonly IModbusFactory _modbusFactory;
      private IModbusMaster _master;
      private TcpClient _tcpClient;
      // private imodbus
      private IModbusSlaveNetwork _slaveNetwork;
      private TcpListener _tcpListener;
      IPAddress iphost = IPAddress.Any;
      IPAddress ipclient = IPAddress.Any;
      int tcpport = 502;
      byte _slaveid = 1;
      private static Action _Action; // = new Action(() => Update()
      TestCtrlMgr _TestCtrl;
      MainWindowModel _Model;
      object mylock = new object();

      public ModbusManager(MainWindowModel model)
      {
          _Model = model;
          _TestCtrl = _Model.m_TestCtrlMgr;
          _modbusFactory = new ModbusFactory();          
          ipclient = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.108");  //my dev laptop , client       

          // ip = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 1, 82 }); //server pc where modscan runs
          //192.168.1.82


          if (_ModbusMode == 0)
              OpenDevice(); //open slave device
          else
              OpenTCPDevice();

          Modbus_Poll_Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
          // TGA_Poll_Timer.Interval = 3000;
          Modbus_Poll_Timer.Interval = 1000;
          // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
          Modbus_Poll_Timer.Elapsed += OnModbusTimerEvent;
          // Have the timer fire repeated events (true is the default)
          Modbus_Poll_Timer.AutoReset = true;
          // Start the timer
          Modbus_Poll_Timer.Enabled = true;
          _Action = new Action(() => Exchange());

      }

      private void Exchange()
      {
          try
          {
              _Model.MainAppWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(_Action /*new Action(() => Update())*/);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {

          }
      }

      ~ModbusManager()
      {

      }



      private void OnModbusTimerEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
      {

          //var performanceData = _devicePerformance.GetPerformanceInfo();
          //periodically write data to modbus master;
          lock(mylock)
          { 
              WriteData();
          }

      }

      public void WriteData()
      {
          ushort address = 0;  //0 = 40001 for WriteMultipleRegs
          ushort[] registers = new ushort[] { 1, 2, 3,4,5 };

          Write(_slaveid, address, registers);
       
      }

      public void OpenDevice() //opens slave device
      {
          using (SerialPort slavePort = new SerialPort(PrimarySerialPortName))
          {
              // configure serial ports
              slavePort.BaudRate = 9600;
              slavePort.DataBits = 8;
              slavePort.Parity = Parity.None;
              slavePort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
              slavePort.Open();

              // _master = _modbusFactory.CreateMaster(slavePort);

              /////     var slaveAdapter = new SerialPortAdapter(slavePort);
              // create modbus slave on seperate thread
              byte slaveId = 1;
              /*    _slave = ModbusSerialSlave.CreateAscii(slaveId, slavePort);
                  _slave.DataStore = DataStoreFactory.CreateDefaultDataStore();
                  _slave.DataStore.DataStoreWrittenTo += DataStore_DataStoreWrittenTo;
                  // var listenTask = slave.ListenAsync();               
                  _slave.ModbusSlaveRequestReceived += Slave_ModbusSlaveRequestReceived;
                  //_slave.*/

          }
      }

      public void OpenTCPDevice() //opens slave device
      { 
          
          CreateServer(ipclient, tcpport); //for reading
          StartServer();
          CreateMaster(ipclient, tcpport); //for writing

      }

      public void CreateMaster(IPAddress ip, int port)
      {
          if (_tcpClient != null)
              return;

          _tcpClient = new TcpClient();

          // _tcpClient.Client.Connect(ip,port);
          try
          {
              _tcpClient.Connect(ip, 502);
          }
          catch (ArgumentNullException e)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
          }
          catch (SocketException e)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
          }
          catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException e)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
          }
          catch (System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException e)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
          }
          finally
          {
           //_tcpClient.Close(); will be called with/without exception
 
          }   

          
          //_tcpClient.Connect(ip,502);
          _master = _modbusFactory.CreateMaster(_tcpClient);
          
      }
      public void Write(byte unitId, ushort address, ushort[] data)
      {

          if (_master == null)
              return;
          try
          {
              _master.WriteMultipleRegisters(unitId, address, data);                
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {

          }
          
      }
      public void CreateServer(IPAddress ip, int port)
      {
          _tcpListener = new TcpListener(ip, port);
          _tcpListener.Start();
          _slaveNetwork = _modbusFactory.CreateSlaveNetwork(_tcpListener);
          AddSlave(_slaveid);
      }
      public void AddSlave(byte unitId)
      {
           var slave = _modbusFactory.CreateSlave(unitId);
           _slaveNetwork.AddSlave(slave);
         
      }
      public void StartServer()
      {
          _slaveNetwork.ListenAsync();
      }
      public void Dispose()
      {
          _master?.Dispose();
          _master = null;
          _tcpClient?.Close();
          _tcpClient = null;

          _slaveNetwork?.Dispose();
          _slaveNetwork = null;
          _tcpListener?.Stop();
          _tcpListener = null;
      }     
  }

Above code sample is what i tried and did not see any values in modscan. Modscan connects to the slave and good polling status and response , just unable see the values written from the client.
I can see the values in modscan now. see picture.enter image description here

Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example. i.e. if you are using TCP then remove anything to do with serial from your example. One issue I spotted is that in CreateMaster you are calling _tcpClient.Close(); so the client will be closed before you actually do anything with it (stuff in finally gets run whether there is an exception or not). You also ignore exceptions in Write (please log them at minimum!).

I do not think the question is very clear. The "Slave" is equivalent to a "server", so the master will connect to, and write/read from the slave. You can set the slaves registers to whatever you want, but the master still have to connect and read the registers. Your example contains code for both slave and master, as well as serial, so it is not really clear what is going on.

@Prabha the comment "I can see the values" makes it appear that it is probably fixed. If that is the case please consider adding an answer (or at least clearly state "this issue is resolved" in the question) - otherwise others may well try to help. If it's not fixed then please provide an update as to the current issue (i.e. what error you are seeing).

@Brits After i removed the _tcpclient.close() from finally block, the values written from client are seen in the master. Ran for few hours. Then i exit the application. When i re run the c# application, i am seeing exception. Need to figure out why it is throwing an exception. see exception details below.

System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(System.Net.EndPoint, System.Net.SocketAddress) in Socket.cs
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(System.Net.EndPoint) in Socket.cs
System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(int) in TcpListener.cs
System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start() in TcpListener.cs
WpfTGAHmi.ModbusManager.OpenTCPDevice() in ModbusManager.cs

SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

@Prabha - OK, that looks like a different issue (the application is probably not shutting down, you geneally can't have two things listening on the same port).
